# Will both of these Regex terms find the same matches using C# isMatch() method?

Tags: c#, .net, regex

Will a regex created with the following terms match the same results?

```
"canon| eos" "1d"
```

and

```
canon|eos 1d
```

Now I do not want to match the quotation marks (") in the string. Will the fact they are in there make a difference.

Will the first term match "canon but not canon?

Am I right in what I am saying?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are two completely different expressions. What makes you think that they are the same?

The first expression will match either `"canon` or `␣eos"␣"1d"`.

The second expression will match `canon` or `eos␣1d`.

Comment: My point is that they are completely different expressions, it's what i've told a client. That their input file has incorrect expressions (because they do not want the quotation mark to be matched, yet they have included it). I needed a definite answer from somebody else as a "second opinion"

Comment: Kondrad is right. If the two expressions you show are full regular expressions in themselves (ie not including any delimiters) then the first will match `"cannon` or ` eos" "1d"` (notice there is a space before `eos` also). The second will match `canon` or `eos 1d`